# Wordpress admin login cookies blocked error after moving servers

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

Background: had a working Wordpress 3.7 site at olddomain.com.

I moved it to newdomain.com successfully, and in the process added this to wp-config:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://newdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://newdomain.com');
```

Now when I attempt to login from newdomain.com/wp-admin I'm getting the cross-browser error (despite having cookies enabled and clearing existing cookies):

```
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by // your browser. 
You must enable cookies to use WordPress.
```

I tried going into wp-login.php and commenting out the following lines (744-747) to stop the conditional testcookie check

```
    // If cookies are disabled we can't log in even with a valid user+pass
if ( isset($_POST['testcookie']) && empty($_COOKIE[TEST_COOKIE]) )
    $user = new WP_Error('test_cookie', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: Cookies are blocked or not supported by // your browser. You must <a href='http://www.google.com/cookies.html'>enable cookies</a> to use WordPress."));
else
    $user = wp_signon('', $secure_cookie);
```

but doing that leaves me stuck in a redirect loop back to the admin page:

```
http://myapp.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

Do I need to change (or not set) the site URL? or is there another potential way to troubleshoot this? thanks

Comment: General Troubleshooting:- `1.` Have you considered updating to the most recent version of WordPress? `2.` Deactivate all plugins and see if the problem is solved or not. If problem solved then reactivate them one by one to see who is making the problem.

Comment: The challenge is that since I can't access the admin dashboard I have to manually deactive plugins and upgrade wordpress via FTP. May be my last resort but makes it difficult to control for changes across the site. I might miss some plugin-generated code or update something in WP that creates additional complications.

Comment: Tried deactivating all plugins (and mu-plugins), didn't resolve

Comment: In bad situations you can force deactivate plugins by renaming the folder containing the plugin. wp-content/plugins/plugin_name to wp-content/plugins/X_plugin_name - just tested w/akismet -> breaks the activation.

Comment: I suspected W3 Total Cache plugin was involved somehow but deactivated it by deleting plugin and removed advanced-cache.php, object-cache.php and db.php from wp-content, still stuck

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Having migrated hundreds of WP sites, here's a few thoughts :

If migrating the DB : Check the database options table (probably wp_options) column "option_name" that values "siteurl" and "home" have the correct "option_value" for your site. "siteurl" is huge.

I can testify that the options table tweak is the bare minimum required to migrate a DB to a new domain in WP. (will not cause redirection, will still have issues)

WP looks up these DB options to serialize the site to domain and I am pretty sure the defines are lower in the stack and of no help. Consider the wp-admin activities as loosely coupled to the front.  You can break everything (done it) in the front and the admin will still function.

Also - did/does the site work with generic install/no migration or tweaks?

As mentioned - .htaccess (missing or misconfigured) will cause your error. Regarding the .htaccess file, if used, this is a dot.file and many operating systems will "ignore" or "make invisible" so a copy/paste or FTP application or similar may not carry the .htaccess

(pretty sure on this) If you moved the DB and used pretty urls, and missed the .htaccess that could be all you need to fix. I just tested locally on a sandbox install and the table wp_option column "option_name" value  "permalink_structure" when left blank in column option_value will return to ?p=1 (non-permalink) status and .htaccess will be mostly bypassed.

Comment: Awesome. Changing siteurl in wp_options to new domain solved the problem. Huge thanks

Comment: Cool, I learned the HARD way years ago. Remember - all your old image and relative links will probably be busted now. I have a dirty hack script for migrations I use -- it is not for the weak at heart. msg me if you want a github link.

Comment: I remember using a 'simple' mysql find (old url) and replace (new url) the content and extra tables.

Comment: @seveneves - here is a very dirty version of that script (use with caution) https://github.com/datamafia/junk_drawer/blob/master/iz_wordpress_data_migration_helper.php back up DB first!!! if you do this wrong it is all hurt all day long. But this is the script I use to migrate, will treat the image/resource links. It is also a security issue and huge MySL resource hog and can also gobble up data you don't want (other non WP tables). So be careful!

Comment: Your first approach is pretty accurate. Checked wordpress db and found both home and siturl values pointing to my localhost. Updated them to the actual domain and the Cookies problem was gone. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thx. siturl should be for "am I at the right site". There are some hacks to get around this - but larger projects call for unique DBs per env - so I prefer to write scripts to transform on the DB level. When you have 3+ envs (dev/stage/prod+) you need to not write the exception in the PHP. Instead the code should flow through environments untouched.

Comment: if you are moving db from live to local, always have "http://" to your localhost instead of this "//locahost:8080/mysite" -> must have http like this "http://localhost:8080/mysite"

Answer (score 49):

add to wp-config.php

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

original source http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cookie-error-site-not-letting-me-log-in

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me... I was stuck for pretty long time.. You are a saver..

Comment: This should be added above `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging.  */`

Comment: worked for me too. and you can remove the above after you login successfully

Comment: Thats perfect! Working fine.

Comment: This works for the cookie issue on Wordpress Multisite! Thanks

Comment: this is just Perfect! I've solved my issue after add ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

1. Remove `//define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.domain.com');`in your wp-config.php
2. Ensure that all the files have the ANSI format and not utf-8

Comment: I didn't have the `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.domain.com;` commented out so I removed it and that seems to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

This error also occurs when moving a multisite installation to a new domain if you update all options on the database table (usually `wp_options`), but forget to change the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` line on `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'yourdomain.com' );
```

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this due to my caching plugin.

W3 Total Cache had added the following to my wp-config.php file:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.olddomain.com'); // Added by W3 Total Cache
```

Since it was hard coded, it didn't update to the new site domain. After deleting the added code (because I don't currently use the plugin), I was able to log in again.

I'd check wp-config.php for the word "cookie" to see if a plugin might have added something like this.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this same error.

I had hard coded the Home and SiteURL in wp-config.php for a brand new website - no plugins even installed.

The problem:  I had a space at the end of the URL.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://100.000.000.01/~acctname/wp ');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://100.000.000.01/~acctname/wp ');
```

Removing the space fixed this error.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://100.000.000.01/~acctname/wp');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://100.000.000.01/~acctname/wp');
```

Comment: Had similar problem that caused the cookie error: a space at the end of my url when I updated wp_options info.

Answer (score 3):

this bug was driving me crazy the last couple of days so i thought after fixing it to share with you guys! the problem was when i was trying to login into my wordpress backend i got this annoying cookies error so this is how i fixed it!

1. Go to your ftp and your domain.
2. Afterwards go to your wp-contents
3. Go to your themes folder
4. Chose the theme that is active
5. Look for functions.php of your teem and open it
6. At the ende of the code you should see closing tag p> just remove it clear the spaces also and save it!
7. Go to your domain.com/wp-login.php
8. and try to login it should be fixed afterwards you can put the tag back where it was and save it again that was the solution for me this trick also fixes the white page problem in wordpress

Cheers!

Comment: This is awesome. And stupid also. Would never have found this on my own, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I have been googled & tried all ways to get rid of this cookie issue. Finally i found two solutions, which could help you.

**Solution 1:**

yoursite/wp-login.php

Comment following lines 770-773

Code

```
if ( isset($_POST['testcookie']) && empty($_COOKIE[TEST_COOKIE]) )
    $user = new WP_Error('test_cookie', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must <a href='http://www.google.com/cookies.html'>enable cookies</a> to use WordPress."));
else
    $user = wp_signon('', $secure_cookie);
```

It might work for some websites and some sites may show blank page. Moreover, this is not recommended,as this file may be overridden after wordpress update so try for second solution.

**Solution 2:**

yoursite/wp-content/themes/yourthemeFolder/functions.php

Place following code.

```
 setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH )
    setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

Updating of your theme may also loose these changes so please place this code in another functions.php, which is under your child-theme folder in your current active theme. Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Don't edit core files of WordPress, that's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running on a Unix/Linux type platform - please ensure you have copied your .htaccess file from your original server and updated any references to the old domain within that file. It will be in the root of your wordpress deployment (if you are using it).

Either that or you may have a reference to your old domain somewhere in your wp_options table within the database.

Be forewarned that as you have moved from one domain to another, images and media locations within posts may need to be updated. You can either do that yourself directly within the database, use a find/replace utility or manually re-point your images within your posts. An alternative method to fix your post data is to export all your posts from your old site (from within the admin panel) - Tools > Export > All posts; then manually update the URL within that resultant file before importing to your new site.

All of this and much more is covered over at **codex.wordpress.org**. For more information see this link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

**IMPORTANT NOTES:**

1. If you are going to modify anything directly within the database, **make sure you read the section that talks about GUIDs**
2. If you are using [Better WP Security](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/), **there are other things you may need to do**, but based on what you are describing, I doubt you have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with very similar circumstances and spec.

Eventually after trying all sorts of different solutions suggested online, I just renamed my active theme via FTP and then was able to login to the dashboard, I renamed my theme back and everything worked, I've no idea why but it may help somebody fix issues they're having.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried renaming the theme via FTP but it didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and nothing works. After upgrading my php 5.3.x to 5.4.x it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following step solve my issue

on wp-config.php

```
//define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache Block this line
//define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.domain.com"); Block this line
```

Delete following files from wp-content

```
object-cache.php 
advanced-cache.php
db.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my Multisite install long ago when you needed a plugin for domain mapping. So I had the file `'/wp-content/sunrise.php'` and in the wp-config `define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );` It's been working just fine until a recent update to WordPress.

I viewed these errors in my debug.log:

```
Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in ../public_html/wp-content/sunrise.php on line 10
Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in ../public_html/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 57
```

So I deleted the sunrise file and wp-config sunrise definition and added @max4ever/@duck_boy's cookie definitions to the wp-config file:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

That solved the problem. I can now login!! Note: I tried this definition and it worked as well. Taken from [Multisite Setup Guide](http://www.jamesnickles.com/blog/domain-mapping-without-plugin-wordpress-multisite-installation/)

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when trying to install a wordpress site on localhost. The problem was this line inside the .htaccess

> Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure

It prevents cookies being set if not on https. Just had to remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

I have found very good solution of this issue

There are possible following solutions for this error

1. Coding Error
2. Unnecessary Spaces in Code
3. Caching & Security Plugin

Check this article: https://www.scratchcode.io/cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser/