# Cannot login to WordPress Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, wordpress-theming

Some strangeness here. 
So I have build a custom theme for a client about a year ago and all has worked perfectly till about 3 days ago when I noticed that I could not login to the website. I kept and still keep getting the '**ERROR**: Cookies are blocked' warning on the website.

At the time my client still had access but now he no longer has access and is just getting the same warning!

I had the Cerber plugin running on the site and I had a custom login url namely example.com/myadminlogin/ also when both of us tried to goto example.com/wp-admin/ it redirected us to the 404 page as it should. I went about to use the fix Cerber provides called WP Cerber Reset provided on its website [quickhelp](http://wpcerber.com/quickhelp/) page.

This changed the login link to the default /wp-login.php and I tried again and I still got the '**ERROR**: Cookies are blocked' warning! I tried again on 4 different machines and on three different browsers namely FF, Chrome and Edge. Weirdly when I tried to goto the /wp-admin/ it redirected me back to the login page with this link:
https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I then google searched a fix for the ERROR cookies a blocked warning and found this [fix](https://www.steckinsights.com/how-to-fix-a-cookies-blocked-error-on-wordpress-admin-dashboard/#.WWXH49Eo9QJ). Which I implemented on my functions.php file again I am still getting the Same error and both my client and I are still getting the same issues.

I have checked the .htaccess file and that looks perfectly fine with just the default WordPress code within it.

I put in a support ticket to my hosting company explaining all of this and after close to 16 hours I get this reply...

> I have spent a while trying a number of different things to resolve
>   this however I havn't been successful in logging into the WordPress
>   admin section. I have tried disabled all plugins for the site which
>   hasn't resolved this problem and most of the suggestion on WordPress
>   forum.
>
> I would recommend changing to one of the default WordPress themes and
>   then try logging into the wp-admin section, as it's the only other
>   option I can think of.

How do I go about changing to a default WordPress theme when I cannot even login is my main question?. Also I have re-uploaded a fresh new copy of WordPress to the site via ftp and again this has made zero difference.

Many thanks and any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Phillip Dews

Comment: check it out, Maybe it will work for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941328/wordpress-admin-login-cookies-blocked-error-after-moving-servers

Comment: Did you make any updates? Through WP Dashboard or .php files?

Answer (score 1):

just login to your hosting cpanel and open file manager rename Cerber plugin folder and then try to login to your site.

Comment: Thanks Mahipal, Have tried this and no luck. still getting the ERROR: Cookies are blocked warning!

Comment: can you give us url to check , as may be your browser will block cookie or your network firewall block something for your domain

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

Add the following code to the bottom of the functions.php file:

```
setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH ) setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

Or another solution is to update wp_config file:

What you can do is,add ob_start() at top of wp-config.php. After that,update one of plugin. Then you do logout and remove ob_start().

Comment: Have tried that fix Hardika already as I explained above! Made no difference.

Comment: May this will help you :  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208878/login-page-error-cookies-are-blocked-due-to-unexpected-output